# Rails display attribute through indirect association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

New to rails here. My associations are setup as below, it might not be the ideal way so any recommendation is greatly welcomed:

```
User has many posts (posts table has user_id)
User has one profile (profile table has user_id)
```

Within my post controller view, I want to display the name of the profile (profile.name) that belongs to the user who owns the post.

My naive first guess was `<%= @post.user.profile.name %>` but that obviously didn't work.

This is the association defined in my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_one :profile
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is the code in the view: <%= @post.user.profile.name %>

The error is undefined method profile

Comment: thank you for the edit/response. The error is undefined method for profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to mention the following in your models
user.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_one :profile
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then `<%= @post.user.profile.name %>` should work.

And if still there is a problem in your data

Comment: I have exactly that in my model. The error "is undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: ok that means you have dirty data in your database i.e. there is no user with id `x` where as `user_id` for `@post` is `x`. Hence `@post.user` gives you `nil` instead of `User object`. You can modify your code like following `<%= @post.user.profile.name if @post.user %>` to make it work

Comment: Perfect! it was the dirty data issue. Now I understand why it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `belongs_to` relation in `posts` and `profile` model to get this work. Eg:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Do the same with the `profile` model as well